# Помогите понять, как это сделать

Tags: href

Как в современных сайтах, в сайт-баре, делают ссылку, при нажатии на которую, тебе загружается нужная информация, например, ты открыл сайт - там есть сайт-бар и, множество категорий, ты выбрал, например, категорию "Сказки", и вот тебе внизу загрузилась нужная информация, но при этом, сайт-бар остается на месте, меняется только нижняя чась сайта...Если сделать простую ссылку на страницу, тебе откроется новая.

Comment: контент веб страницы можно менять динамически, при помощи javascript, без видимых переходов по страницам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по нажатии на кнопку загружать данные динамически, используя Ajax

```
<a>Сказки</a>

$('a').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function(data){
      $('div).html(data);
    }
  });
});

<div>Сюда загрузятся данные по нажатии на ссылку</div>
```

Или менять, добавлять их без загрузки

```
<a>Сказки</a>

$('a').on('click', function () {
  $('div).text('Текст');
});

<div>Сюда вставятся данные по нажатии на ссылку</div>
```

Comment: Если использовать дивы, (менять, а не загружать страницу) Хороший ли это вариант? А лучше посоветуйте, какой вариант больше подходит...?

Comment: Всё зависит от ваших задач. Какую именно информацию вы хотите загружать. Можно создать блок c информацией, скрыть его `display:none` и в нужный момент показывать его, использую `show()`

Comment: Ладно, спасибо большое.